# How does AuthExceptionRetryInterval and RestartAfterAuthExceptions interact in Spring Kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

Spring Kafka has introduced the container property RestartAfterAuthExceptions. The documentation for this property says
"
True to restart the container if it is stopped due to authorization/authentication exceptions.
"

However there is also an AuthExceptionRetryInterval property than can be set.

The documentation for this property says:
"
When not null, a Duration to sleep between polls when an AuthenticationException or AuthorizationException is thrown by the Kafka client. When null, such exceptions are considered fatal and the container will stop."

However there is no documentation on which property takes precedence. I'm assuming that if AuthExceptionRetryInterval is set it will take precedence. That is, the container will not stop due to an authorization/authentication exception. It will keep running indefinitely with delays between polling set to the rety interval-this has the affect of ignoring the RestartAfterAuthExceptions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct; see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2612

`restartAfterAuthExceptions` creates a new consumer whereas `authExceptionRetryInterval` is simply a delay between polls when an auth exception occurs.

The former is intended for use with rotating auth tokens; there is no delay in that case.